# php.activerecord does a wildcard not work?

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I'm really new to php.activerecord. So bare with my ignorance. Is there a means of doing a wildcard in a query with it? ie: "Some%" and it returns something, someone, somewhat, somewhere...

http://www.phpactiverecord.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken straight from the [phpactiverecord documentation](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Finders)

```
# fetch all the cheap books!
Book::all(array('conditions' => 'price < 15.00'));
# sql => SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE price < 15.00

# fetch all books that have "war" somewhere in the title
Book::find('all', array('conditions' => "title LIKE '%war%'"));
# sql => SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE title LIKE '%war%'
```

Comment: yea it wasn't til later I realized I completely was trying to do everything completely wrong.. not just the wild card bit. Thank you.

Comment: @tobydavies Thanks for this. It helped me a lot after struggling so much time and it never hit me. However, is it possible to have a mix of conditions that include a like in this format array('conditions' => array('cond1', 'cond2') say cond1 is any normal condition and cond2 is a LIKE condition?

Comment: @LuyandaSiko http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Finders#conditions, the second example block in that section has the syntax for multiple conditions.